# get ERROR:File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it' but it is not missing

Tags: json, firebase, android-studio

I have already include google-services.json file in my app but it still give me error. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> :app:processDebugGoogleServices

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.

I did all the steps according to the guide and add the file to the right place.

what can I do?

please help me:(

Comment: Could this error: "Build failed" be caused by an antivirus installed on my computer?